# Disable left and right controls when first and last time is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

How can i disable left control when first item is active and same goes to right if last item is active then disable right control

i would appreciate if i get any suggestions, is there any alternative for this
Thanks

JsFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/n4v63g3L/3/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
                <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                    <!-- Quote 1 -->
                    <div class="item active">
                        <blockquote>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,ore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni !</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Quote 2 -->
                    <div class="item">
                        <blockquote>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,ore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni !</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Quote 3 -->
                    <div class="item">
                        <blockquote>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,ore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni !</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mantia/128.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
               <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `slid.bs.carousel` bootstrap event

**1. Show or Hide controls**

```
jQuery("#quote-carousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    //Show or Hide left indicator 
    if($(this).find('li:first-child').hasClass('active')){
        $(this).find('.left').hide();
    }else{
        $(this).find('.left').show();
    }

    //Show or Hide right indicator 
    if($(this).find('li:last').hasClass('active')){
        $(this).find('.right').hide();
    }else{
        $(this).find('.right').show();
    }
}).trigger('slid.bs.carousel');
```

**2. For Disabling the controls**

You can disable it using CSS `pointer-events`. 
See here for complete code, https://jsfiddle.net/n4v63g3L/6/

Comment: Wow can i ask you something, the best way to lean JS ? can you suggest me anything it would be great

Comment: The best way is only by writing coding... create a game using JS which will help to learn many things. Refer MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @babuharry Take a look at my GitHub page, http://iamkumaran.github.io/ I learn and release something to keep myself updated. Hope this helps.